# How to create a layout in flutter

Tags: flutter, date-range

I have a layout interface and I want to implement the code in flutter.
please give me an example implementation layout in the flutter interface like the picture below. Please help me. Thank you.

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new SafeArea(
        child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Riwayat'),
      ),
      body: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: content.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                          new Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Expanded(
                                  child: new Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text(
                                    'Transaksi',
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                        color: Colors.black87,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  new Text('12/12/2019'
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12.0,
                                        color: Colors.black54,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                          new Divider(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
    ));
  }
```

this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1fk2.png)

Comment: Please share some code and let us know what you've already tried. Also check the [ask] section. Your layout can be achieved in several different approached e.g. Columsn & Rows, maybe the Cards class for the design of the posts.

Comment: i was be shared some code. sorry I new in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a basic layout in Flutter using the widgets: Container, Row, and Column. There are other widgets, but these are the basic ones.

You can use the child property in Container widget to add a Row or Column. 
You can use the children property in Row and Column widgets to add other widgets. You keep nesting these widgets until you have your desired layout.

The link here will help you get started:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout

And here is some sample code to understand rows and columns:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: Home(),
        );
      }
    }

    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('row column test'),
            ),
            body: TestRowWith3TestColumns()); //replace with TestRow or TestColumn
      }
    }

    class TestRow extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child:Text('row child 1')
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                child:Text('row child 2'),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child:Text('row child 3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class TestColumn extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child:Text('column child 1')
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                child:Text('column child 2'),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child:Text('column child 3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class TestRowWith3TestColumns extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TestColumn(),
              TestColumn(),
              TestColumn(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: expectations https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1fk2.png vs reality https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVrJz.png as usual